# How to set a delay for the animated Image in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, image, animation, swiftui, delay

I want to make an animal blink the eyes with different delays `Int.random(in: 1..<9)`

The **problem** is:

There are solutions for `UIView` animations and async thread delays... But is there any method for `UIImage.animatedImage` to make a delay between the blinks?

If there are no methods at all - how can I solve my issue?

> The code:

File for all animations:

```
 import SwiftUI
  struct AnimalAnimation: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var animalImages: [UIImage?]
    @Binding var size: CGRect

    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UIView {

        let someView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: size.minX, y: size.minY , width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let someImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let animated = UIImage.animatedImage(with: animalImages as! [UIImage], duration: 0.9)!

        someImage.clipsToBounds = true
        someImage.autoresizesSubviews = true
        someImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        someImage.image = animated
        someView.addSubview(someImage)
        return someView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AnimalAnimation>) {
    }
  }
```

I'm using this in `ContentView`'s `body`

```
            VStack {
                    AnimalAnimation(animalImages: $animal1Array, size: $animal1Size)
            }
```

The images:

```
animalImages = [UIImage(named: "eyes-open"),UIImage(named: "eyes-closed")]
```

Comment: And where are the blinks? It is not clear in-between what the delay is expected.

Comment: @Asperi, **animalImages = [UIImage(named: "eyes-open"),UIImage(named: "eyes-closed")]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is SwiftUI only variant. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4. (Sizes/frames if needed can be configured, for demo it does not matter)

[image: demo]

```
struct EyesBlinkView: View {

    enum EyesState: String {
        case open = "eyes-open"
        case closed = "eyes-closed"
    }

    @State private var eyesState = EyesState.open
    var body: some View {
        Image(eyesState.rawValue).resizable().scaledToFit()
            .onAppear { self.blink() }
    }

    private func blink() {
        self.eyesState = .closed
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.9) {
            self.eyesState = .open

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: 
                  DispatchTime.now().advanced(by: .seconds(Int.random(in: 1..<9)))) {
                self.blink()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aspari, Perfect enough) What if we have 7-10 idle objects for eyes? Wouldn't it harm our memory?

Comment: @Oleksandr, hmmm... hard to say... the size of this struct value is 16 bytes ))... one cool guy said one day that 64kB memory should be enough for any program - your 10 values would satisfy that. I think so. 8^)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just add the same image again in the array so it "looks like" a delay?

Comment: It's not a machinegun ))) It is idle objects. They have to blink the eyes once per 1-9 seconds. If I put one more image - they will clip just more often. 
If to make a huge "duration" - it won't be blinking at all.